# Custom jQuery - add data-filter to <select><option>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need make a modification to a custom jQuery script.

**I've got a custom jQuery script which does the following:**

- it converts a standard HTML un-ordered list into a `<select>` dropdown
- it converts the list-items to clickable `<options>`
- the `<select>` is hidden on desktop and only shown on mobile
- all of this works great and here's a screenshot: [image]

---

All is working well, however I need an additional attribute to be added to each `<option>`

- Notice how each HTML list item has (data-filter=".term-x")
- I need this to also be added to each `<option>` in the `<select>` dropdown

---

**Here's what the final HTML output looks like on the page after script has run and done it's thing:**

```
<div id="horizontal_nav">
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/horizontal-nav/" data-filter=".term-3"><span><strong>Horizontal Nav</strong></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/full-width/" data-filter=".term-4"><span><strong>Full Width</strong></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/blog/" data-filter=".term-3"><span><strong>Blog</strong></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/cart/" data-filter=".term-4"><span><strong>Cart</strong></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/checkout/" data-filter=".term-5"><span><strong>Checkout</strong></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/features/" data-filter=".term-5"><span><strong>Features</strong></span></a></li>
</ul>
<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="">More in this section...</option>
    <option value="http://localhost.local/site/horizontal-nav/">Horizontal Nav</option>
    <option value="http://localhost.local/site/full-width/">Full Width</option>
    <option value="http://localhost.local/site/blog/">Blog</option>
    <option value="http://localhost.local/site/cart/">Cart</option>
    <option value="http://localhost.local/site/checkout/">Checkout</option>
    <option value="http://localhost.local/site/features/">Features</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**Here's the jQuery that creates the `<select>` and needs the modification mentioned above**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery("<select />").appendTo("#horizontal_nav");
    jQuery("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value": "",
        "text": php_data.mobile_sub_menu_text
    }).appendTo("#horizontal_nav select");
    jQuery("#horizontal_nav a").each(function() {
        var el = jQuery(this);
        jQuery("<option />", {
            "value": el.attr("href"),
            "text": el.text()
        }).appendTo("#horizontal_nav select")
    });
    jQuery("#horizontal_nav select").change(function() {
        window.location = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val()
    })
};

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("<select />").appendTo("#horizontal_nav");
  jQuery("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
    "value": ""
  }).appendTo("#horizontal_nav select");
  jQuery("#horizontal_nav a").each(function() {
    var el = jQuery(this);
    jQuery("<option />", {
      "value": el.attr("href"),
      "text": el.text(),
      "data-filter": el.attr('data-filter')//add it here
    }).appendTo("#horizontal_nav select")
  });
  jQuery("#horizontal_nav select").change(function() {
    window.location = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").val()
  })


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="horizontal_nav">
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/horizontal-nav/" data-filter=".term-3"><span><strong>Horizontal Nav</strong></span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/full-width/" data-filter=".term-4"><span><strong>Full Width</strong></span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/blog/" data-filter=".term-3"><span><strong>Blog</strong></span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/cart/" data-filter=".term-4"><span><strong>Cart</strong></span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/checkout/" data-filter=".term-5"><span><strong>Checkout</strong></span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost.local/site/features/" data-filter=".term-5"><span><strong>Features</strong></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

add an `.attr()` name it `data-filter` then append the data-filter from the ul

Comment: Brilliant! This works perfectly. Thank you so much!

There is however another issue I now see...

I am using this "data-filter" attribute in conjunction with the isotope script to "filter" items on a page. The "filtering" doesn't seem to work within [select] however there does seem to be an option for filtering with [select]

My knowledge is limited but here is the documentation for isotope: http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/jubmr

Can my custom script perhaps be further modified so the filtering will work within the [select]?

Apologies for improper terminology

Comment: how do you do the filtering please clarify all the info?

Comment: dont you need something like this `itemSelector: '.element-item',` in your code as well this is from the link you gave earlier

Comment: hmm...never needed that in the past....just added it and it had no effect...let me go back to the drawing board and see what I can come up with. Thank you so very much for your help! :)

Comment: @scorey25 np mate happy coding :)